# I hadn't played basketball for a long time

Tags: meaning

**Sentence:**

I hadn't played basketball for a long time until two days ago.

**Question:**

Does the above sentence mean: "I played basketball two days ago; I hadn't played for a long time."? Or does it mean: "Two days ago I played basketball for a long time. Before that, I had only played for short periods of time."? Thanks.

Comment: It's inherently ambiguous, but the long-match reading is unlikely. In speaking, intonation would differentiate.

Comment: I view the "for" in the first sentence as being misused.  It ought to be "***in*** a long time"   Have I said it that way when speaking?  Probably.  Would I notice it and change it in a piece of writing?  Definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I take the meaning to be your first ("I played basketball two days ago; I hadn't played for a long time."). In order to mean the second, it would need to be rendered something like:

> I had never played basketball for very long at a time until two days ago.

However, having said that, the original sentence would be clearer by beginning with the prepositional phrase in order to emphasize it, like this:

> Until two days ago, I hadn't played basketball for [or *in*] a long time.

Comment: There's a Mitch Hedberg joke based on the atypical interpretation of such phrasing - "I haven't slept for three days, because that would be too long."